# Enqueing and threading error with tensorflow while fetching data

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow for fine-tuning a model and it uses threads to enqueue the input queue. The code runs fine for several 1000 iterations but keeps giving following errors after few iterations. However, the code usually quits with couple of these errors after several iterations and I have to manually restart it. Could you please help me to understand the error.

```
Exception in thread Thread-29:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "data_feeder.py", line 212, in enqueue_op_online_val
    model_vars['labels_val']: labels_minibatch})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 717, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 915, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 985, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
NotFoundError: PruneForTargets: Some target nodes not found: fifo_queue_enqueue/fifo_queue_enqueue_4/fifo_queue_enqueue_10/fifo_queue_enqueue_10/fifo_queue_enqueue_8/fifo_queue_enqueue_2/fifo_queue_enqueue_4/fifo_queue_enqueue/fifo_queue_enqueue_3/fifo_queue_enqueue_3/fifo_queue_enqueue/fifo_queue_enqueue_1/fifo_queue_enqueue_5/fifo_queue_enqueue/fifo_queue_enqueue_2/fifo_queue_enqueue/fifo_queue_enqueue_4/fifo_queue_enqueue_6/fifo_queue_enqueue_20/fifo_queue_enqueue_29/fifo_queue_enqueue/fifo_queue_enqueue_7/fifo_queue_enqueue_8/fifo_queue_enqueue_9/fifo_queue_enqueue_7/fifo_queue_enqueue/fifo_queue_enqueue_9/fifo_queue_enqueue_8/fifo_queue_enqueue_11/fifo_queue_enqueue_5/fifo_queue_enqueue_7/fifo_queue_enqueue_8/fifo_queue_enqueue_12/fifo_queue_enqueue_3/fifo_queue_enqueue_2/fifo_queue_enqueue_5/fifo_queue_enqueue_4/fifo_queue_enqueue_7/fifo_queue_enqueue_3/fifo_queue_enqueue/fifo_queue_enqueue_9/fifo_queue_enqueue_1/fifo_queue_enqueue_25/fifo_queue_enqueue_23/fifo_queue_enqueue_30/fifo_queue_enqueue_5/fifo_queue_enqueue_3/fifo_queue_enqueue_7/fifo_queue_enqueue_3/fifo_queue_enqueue/fifo_queue_enqueue_2/fifo_queue_enqueue_8/fifo_queue_enqueue_11/fifo_queue_enqueue_11/fifo_queue_enqueue/fifo_queue_enqueue_4
```

Here's the enqueue op

```
def enqueue_op(self, sess, model_vars, coord):
       queue = model_vars['queue_train']
       random.shuffle(self.keys)
       img_minibatch = np.zeros((self.batch_size, 224, 224, 3))
       #t = time.time()

       for indx in xrange(self.num_batches):
           labels_minibatch = []
           # Load all files in this batch
           for i,k in\
           enumerate(self.keys[indx*self.batch_size:(indx+1)*self.batch_size]):
               img = misc.imread(self.img_path + self.data[k]['filename'])
               img_minibatch[i, :, :, :] = img_proc(img)
               labels_minibatch.append(self.data[k]['labels'])

           labels_minibatch =\
           self.mlb.fit_transform(labels_minibatch).astype(float)
           sess.run([queue.enqueue([model_vars['input'],
                                    model_vars['labels']])],\
                    feed_dict={model_vars['input']: img_minibatch,
                               model_vars['labels']: labels_minibatch})

           if coord.should_stop():
               break
```

Here are the thread creation snippet

```
 thr_train = []
 for i in xrange(12):              

thr_train.append(threading.Thread(target=primary_mb_feeder.enqueue_op,
                                       args=(sess, model_vars, coord)))
                thr_train[-1].setDaemon(True)
                thr_train[-1].start()
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you use to create the enqueue op? The absent node name is very strange, and I wonder if the problem is caused by having multiple threads creating enqueue ops at the same time, when it would be better to create a single op that you reuse across the threads. (It might still be a bug however...)

Comment: I have pasted the code for enqueue operation I am using and code snippet that create threads to run this op.

Comment: What type is `primary_mb_feeder`? Is `enqueue_op` one of its methods, and how is it implemented?

Comment: Sorry for being abstract in the code. Primary_mb_feeder is a simple class that initializes path directories for images and labels. And the enqueue_op is just a method of this call used for feeding the queues.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is caused by the `enqueue_op()` method, which (i) runs in multiple threads, and (ii) creates a new `tf.Operation` for each mini-batch, by calling [`queue.enqueue()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase.enqueue). TensorFlow doesn't support multiple threads adding nodes to the graph at the same time, and it's generally inefficient to do so (because TensorFlow works most efficiently when the graph **doesn't** change).

To fix this problem, I'd encourage you to refactor your code so that you only call `queue.enqueue()` once, share the returned operation between all of the input threads, and use it in each of the `sess.run()` calls that feed in new data.